# REGEXP_SUBSTR oracle 11g

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

All,

I have a input data coming in the following format,

```
"CUStid":["201","217"],"HireDate":"2016-06-24","EndDate":"2016-08-23"
```

(or)

```
"CUStid":["301",""],"HireDate":"2016-06-24","EndDate":"2016-08-23"
```

I need to output just the customer id from the input data, and when I run the following it is returning null

```
(REGEXP_SUBSTR (inputdata,
                                '"CUStid":"([^"]*)"',
                                1,
                                1,
                                NULL,
                                1))
```

expected output is:

```
CUStid1   Custid2  

201         217  

301
```

can someone please tell me how can I do this in oracle 11g

Thanks

Comment: It appears each customer has exactly two id's, one or both of which may be null? Can there be more than two id's, or might there be only one id?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR (inputdata,'"CUStid":"\[(.+)\]"',1,1,null,1)
```

`[` and `]` should be escaped with `\`.

to get `"301",""` ,`"201","217"`

Use string manipulation to get the multiple values as separate columns.

If there can be a maximum of 2 values separated by a `,` use

```
select 
 substr(replace(val,'"',''), 1, instr(replace(val,'"',''),',')-1) custid1
,substr(replace(val,'"',''), instr(replace(val,'"',''),',')+1) custid2
from (select REGEXP_SUBSTR (inputdata,'"CUStid":"\[(.+)\]"',1,1,null,1) val
      from tablename)
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that in your search pattern you are missing a `[`.
It should be:

`'"CUStid":["([^"]*)"'`   (notice the `[` after the colon `:` )

... and actually (TESTING HELPS!) the [ is a metacharacter in regular expressions, so it must be escaped:

`'"CUStid":\["([^"]*)"'`

The longer answer is that you need to be able to pick up the second customer id as well, but perhaps you already know how to do that. Good luck!

**Edited**

Here is the full query:

```
with inputs (inputdata) as (
   select '"CUStid":["201","217"],"HireDate":"2016-06-24","EndDate":"2016-08-23"' from dual
       union all
   select '"CUStid":["301",""],"HireDate":"2016-06-24","EndDate":"2016-08-23"' from dual
  )
select regexp_substr(inputdata, '"CUStid":\["([^"]*)"', 1, 1, null, 1) as custid1,
       regexp_substr(inputdata, '"CUStid":\["[^"]*","([^"]*)"', 1, 1, null, 1) as custid2
from   inputs;
```

Result:

```
CUSTID1    CUSTID2
---------- ----------
201        217
301

2 rows selected.
```

Comment: I ran the following and it is returning null.

Comment: select REGEXP_SUBSTR (inputdata,'"CUStid":"\[(.+)\]"',1,1,null,1) from  tablename

Comment: i got the first value but still stuck on 2nd value. any suggestions,

Comment: select REGEXP_SUBSTR (inputdata,'"CUStid":\["([^"]*)"',1,1,null,1) from  tablename

Comment: Don't forget to escape the literal [, it should be \\[ (please re-read my answer). As to the second value, I just added the full query to my original answer.